# Resharper Access to modified closure

Tags: c#, selenium, resharper, warnings

Even when I use an `Assert` to the logic not breaks the code, Resharpers stills warning me about the access to modified closure.

There is a way to change it to Resharper stops warning me or a better way to write the same code lines?

The foreach reads all the items in the list, except the last. When lefts one loop to foreach ends, it breaks. My variable `countSubEscala` with the `TakeWhile` calculates it to exit the loop in the last element.

The foreach does not change or remove the list's elements.

```
var subEscalas = Browser.SafeFindElements(By.CssSelector(".subescala tbody tr")).ToList();
var countSubEscala = subEscalas.Count();
Assert.Greater(countSubEscala, 0);

foreach (var x in subEscalas.TakeWhile(x => countSubEscala != 1))
{
    countSubEscala--;

    var seletorExcluir = By.XPath(string.Format("//a[contains(@class,'excluir-subescala')]", countSubEscala - 1));
    Browser.ClickIn(seletorExcluir);
    Browser.Wait(200);
}
```

Comment: If you clarify what you are trying to achieve one can help to come up with alternatives. It is somewhat hard to see how many items you really want to get with all those `--` / `!=1`.

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for "all items except the last" simply taking that many items should work:

```
foreach (var x in subEscalas.Take(subEscalas.Count() - 1))...
```

Note that `subEscalas.Count() - 1` will be computed once in the beginning which is different from current code that get re-evaluated for every item.